# Animating image sprites and outputing scene to gif

Tags: vector-graphics, animation

I have a requirment to take a bunch of ball images, and animate their locations overtime following a curved path.

The scene should ultimately look like a bunch of balls bouncing around in a blower.

Then I would like to output that animation scene to an animated gif.

Are there any free applications that would be suited to this?

So far I have uncovered http://www.synfig.org/

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate free tool for doing this sort of work, (but with quite a steep learning curve), is [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) which is a modelling, rendering, animation, video creation and editing suite - there is even a physics engine that would allow you to make your animation real world accurate.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Selectable detail level up to hi-res photo realism
- Physics Engine
- Strong user community
- Lots of online examples
- You can either output as a video file or as a sequence of frames for later conversion to gif with [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) as in [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Creating_animated_GIFs_using_Blender_and_Gimp) tutorial.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. I already have used blender for video editing and modelling. I should have known it does more.